# How can I set the orientation of a single page in a multi-page document in Word 2007-2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-word-2016

How can I rotate (or insert) a single page into an Office Word document that is oriented differently that the other pages?

I know this can be done.  I've seen in done in Word 2003 and older documents but figuring this out for Office 2007 (and greater) eludes me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This can be a bit confusing since the Word 2007+ context menu on your document is a bit useless.  Regardless, changing the orientation of a single document is simple if you know where to look.

Follow the steps listed below to rotate a single page in your document.

1. First, place your cursor on the page that you would like to rotate.  If you want to insert a new page, you will need to first insert a page break, or two, to create a blank page.
2. Next, Click on the **Page Layout** ribbon header.
3. Contrary to what you would expect, do not click on the **Orientation** option.  Instead, click on the little lower-right-pointing arrow at the bottom of the **Page Setup** section.

   [image: Click on this small button.]
4. This will open the **Page Setup** dialog.  On this screen, set your orientation as desired and set the **Apply to** field to "Selected text".

   [image: Page Setup dialog]
5. Click OK.  Your single page should now be rotated to the layout that you desire.

Comment: +1 That is an awesome short cut to my old way of doing it - manually entering 2 section breaks and changing he orientation of the section